# Removing single pattern from findbugs detector in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, findbugs

Is it possible to remove a single (SE_NO_SERIALVERSIONID) pattern from the SerializableIdiom detector in findbugs in Eclipse Indigo?

The pattern annoys me with messages about serialVersionUID on all serializable classes. I don't want to litter my code just because of some corner cases of serialization. However, I can only remove the whole SerializableIdiom and I want to get a warning if I i.e. try to use an int for serialVersionUID.

**Update:**

On the side. This wasn't what I was after even though it was what I asked for ;-). What I was after was getting rid of the serialVersionID warnings. These are possibly set on many levels. The warnings automatically set is produced by the Eclipse compiler. To remove them: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings and set "Serializable class without serialVersionUID to Ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been looking at the wrong place in the Eclipse preferences, the Findbugs "configuration" tab where you enable/disable the detectors. Instead please use the tab "filter files", add an exclude file filter and put this into the file:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Bug pattern="SE_NO_SERIALVERSIONID" />
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

There is [more that you can filter](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html).